# I have this button, <button type="button" class="">Send</button>. How can i make it send an e-mail?

Tags: html, email

Here is my code :

```
  <form class="w3-container w3-card-4 w3-padding-16 w3-white">
  <div class="w3-group">      
    <label class="w3-label">Your Full Name</label>
    <input class="w3-input" type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="w3-group">      
    <label class="w3-label">Your e-mail</label>
    <input class="w3-input" type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="w3-group">      
    <label class="w3-label">Subject/Order</label>
    <input class="w3-input" type="text">
  </div>  
  <input class="w3-check" type="checkbox" checked>
  <label class="w3-validate">I Like it!</label>
  <button type="button" class="w3-btn w3-right w3-theme">Send</button>
  </form>
```

How can i make the       Send button send an email and designate the email i want ?

Comment: Are you wanting them to email you or you to email them?

Comment: I want them to email me.

Answer (score 0):

There is no feature in HTML to send an e-mail directly to an e-mail address.  Your options are to use a server-side script (with, for example, PHP), or to have the user's web browser invoke their email client to send the form submission to the email address specified.  You can do this by specifying the form action as follows:

```
<form action="mailto:you@yourwebsite.com">
```

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: I already knew about the <form action="mailto:you@yourwebsite.com"> but can I integrate it into my code ? if so, where ? :/

Answer (score 0):

If you want someone viewing your site to email you, you can create an `<a>` link that includes some information in the link that will populate the email for them:

```
<a href="mailto:emailname@yourdomain.com?subject=Subject You Selected">
The text of your link
</a>
```

You can also set the body text as well if you want to.

When they click the link it'll use their default mail program and create an email with your email address and whatever you want as the subject line.

There's a [blog here that tells how to do this in more detail](http://resources.elixiter.com/h/i/183196641-how-to-pre-populate-the-subject-line-and-body-in-mailto-generated-emails).